# How to show only a specific amount of data on a table

Tags: mysql, arrays, database, laravel, boolean

I made a column to my 'users' table called 'approved' which is boolean where 1=true and 0=false. What I want to do in my view is that I only want to show the data of the user with the 0/false value. What are the steps I need to make to achieve this? I'm really new to Laravel or rather at Web Development in general.

Comment: You can do like this `DB::table('users')->where('approved', false)` . But laravel have so many query selection you can view on official site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$datas=User::where('approved','0')->get();
```

Now in your blade use ......

```
@foreach($datas as $data)

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways to do it. First is you can directly use where clause for it like this one.

```
User::where('approved', 0)->get();
```

Second is to use local scope. In your model you will put this one.

```
public function scopeApprovedUser($query) {
   return $query->where('approved', 0);
}
```

and call it to your controller like this.

```
User::approveduser();
```